# The view didn't return an HttpResponse object when use redirect()

Tags: python, django, django-views, modelform

I tried creating model form to add new record to my models in django, but I got this error:

```
The view post.views.add_job_resume didn't return an object. It returned None instead.
```

this is my files(Notice that in this file I have more codes than what I write here):

> view.py

```
def add_job_resume(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = AddJobForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            job_resume = form.save(commit=False)
            job_resume.user= request.user
            job_resume.save()
            return redirect('view_job_resume')

    else:
        form = AddJobForm()
        return render(request, 'education/job_research_education_records/job_resume/add_job_resume.html', {'form': form})
```

> forms.py

```
class AddJobForm(ModelForm):
       class Meta:
        model = JobRecord
        fields = [
            'title',
            'explains',
            'post',
            'organization',
            'time_start',
            'time_end',
            'upload_url',
        ]
```

> models.py

```
class JobRecord(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=False)
    explains = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    post = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    organization = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    time_start = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    time_end = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    upload_url = models.FileField(upload_to='job-resume-files/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

> add_job_resume.html

```
<form method="post" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">add</button>
</form>
```

> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('edu/resume/job/', views.view_job_resume, name='view_job_resume'),
   path('edu/resume/job/add', views.add_job_resume, name='add_job_resume')]
```

I search a lot for this error but I can't solve that! What is going on?

Comment: What if the method is a POST but the form is not valid, then you do not do anything in your view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `redirect(..)` itself. You just forgot a *code path*. It is possible that the method is indeed POST, but that the form is not valid. So the condition in the first `if` is satisfied, but the condition in the second `if` is not. Right now, your view will return nothing (hence return `None`) for this situation.

It is common to simply rerender the template, but now with the invalid form, such that the form can show the errors, like:

```
def add_job_resume(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = AddJobForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            job_resume = form.save(commit=False)
            job_resume.user= request.user
            job_resume.save()
            return redirect('view_job_resume')

    else:
        form = AddJobForm()
    # Not placed under the else
    return render(
        request,
        'education/job_research_education_records/job_resume/add_job_resume.html',
        {'form': form}
    )
```

Notice that the `render` is *not* put under the `else` part. Indeed regardless whether the method is POST and the form is invalid, or the method is *not* POST, we render the page and respond with the rendered page.

Comment: Thanks! An Error is solve.:) I filled the form several times, but none of them could lead to a valid form. What is the problem of invalidity?@willem-van-onsem

Comment: @mostafarahnama: you can print `form.errors` before rendering it, such that the errors are printed on the stdout of the server. Note that you should only construct a new form in the `else` case, otherwise the errors will not show up at the page rendering.

Comment: Ahhaaa. How can I construct a new form in the else case? @willem-van-onsem

Comment: @mostafarahnama: that is already the case in the above code fragment. I'm only saying that you should not create a new one in case of a POST, since otherwise the errors will not show up, since you then render, technically speaking, a different form.

Answer (score 2):

Redirecting is not the problem. The problem is that your form is not valid, and the view does not turn anything if that happens

You should unindent the last line one level, so that it catches this case.